# How can i find the differenct between two time values in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently writing a C# application where a user can record there Sign in and Sign out times each day.
The time is stored on a table with the datatype time(0) so the time appears 09:00:00.
The Columns that store the data are 
Sign_In, Sign_Out

What i am looking to do is show how long a user has worked that day for example Sign_In 09:00:00  Sign_Out 17:00:00  .  eg the difference here is 8 hours.  I have tried researching tish and cannot figure it out. i have tried the below for this.

How do i write Sign_Out subtract Sing_In in a SQL statement ?

Comment: What DBMS are you using ?

Comment: SQL server management studio

Comment: Seems you're missing something critical - the date on which this person worked. And what happens when a person's work time starts before midnight and ends after midnight? Think carefully about your assumptions and your schema.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `datediff()`:

```
select datediff(minute, sign_in, sign_out) as minutes_inside
```

If you want this as hours, I would suggest using fractional hours:

```
select datediff(minute, sign_in, sign_out) / 60.0 as hours_inside
```

Comment: Hi gordon, I get ther error "invalid column name" for both Sign_In & Sign_Out but i have the columns named that ?

Comment: @Johnathan post your SQL. I suspect you're missing your `FROM` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try the following query.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND,@sign_in, @sign_out),0), 108) as ElapsedTime
```

You will get the `elapsedtime` as `hour:minute:second`

Comment: There is no reason to convert to varchar. Nor is style 108 variable length.

Comment: I'm using the convert function to get the hour:minutes:sec from the date. That 108 style returns the same

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(HH, '09:00:00', '17:00:00') AS TotalDiff;
```

To learn more about `Datediff` follow the [**here**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp) or [**this**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).